# Setting a specific character to another font set for page rendering at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, e-commerce

My Client is using a font on the web that doesn't have a character "+" in it. I have a product that is called Clean + Fresh on an e-commerce website, and I can see that when inspecting the element the "+" is loading correctly. The problem is the font that doesn't have this character.

Instead I get "Clean 1 Fresh" rendering on a page.

Is there any way that a piece of code can detect for a PLUS sign in a specific CSS class, and then replace that character with another font that contains that character - for example Arial.

Here is an example of the product CSS entry:

```
<h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">Clean + Fresh </h1>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Wrap it in a span with a class

Answer (score 0):

This is easily solved by wrapping the plus sign in a span, and defining a standard font-family for it.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: cursive;
}

span.plus {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">Clean <span class="plus">+</span> Fresh </h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately this will not work because the element cannot be coded in this way. The item name is a taken from a Wordpress field which cannot accept this type of formatting as it will simply render as text on that page. Still maybe this is going to be helpful for someone else.

Comment: Sure it can. You can enter any item as HTML through whatever editor you're using.  Or create a shortcode.  There is a way to do whatever you want in WordPress

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.